# Firebase security rules cross project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Project A has Firebase Authentication and Project B has Firebase Firestore.
Both Authentication and Firestore are working correctly using:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects (Web)

However when writing the following Project B Firestore Security Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid} {
      allow get: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

I get an error:

```
Missing or insufficient permissions
```

Because the Authentication data is with Project A, there is no `auth` with the Project B Firestore request.

How do I give Project B the authentication information from Project A using JavaScript/Web?

Comment: Authentication tokens are not interchangeable between projects, as that'd be a huge security risk. Why are you using multiple projects?

Comment: If I authenticate with Project A, can I pass the Authentication Token to Project B all on the client-side? I'm using multiple projects for different micro-services of the application, eg: Project A is for handling Authentication, whilst Project B is for handling a different service of the application - But they both still require Authentication.

Comment: I think these instructions still apply: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Can your project A leverage a backend api to manage custom auth? In a project I realized, for support purposes, I make an API call to the backend with the user email and a specific password. When the server receives this credentials, forges a custom firebase token and passes it to the client. From that point on, the operator can act in the application as the user would, reading and writing firestore as well. Could this be suitable for you?

Answer (score 1):

Bluntly, you are "separating your microservices" in completely the wrong way.  Authentication is FUNDAMENTALLY tied to functionality, and inseparable - it is NOT a "micro-service".  Even if you choose to use Cloud Functions to provide your "micro-service API", there is absolutely no reason whatever to use separate projects and databases BEHIND the Cloud Functions, and every reason to keep them the same.

What you are describing sounds far more like an attempt to hack another service than to create a viable solution, and Firestore is specifically built to resist such attempts.

Comment: Implementing authentication separately to all other services is a key concept to microservice architecture, otherwise, microservice architecture would fail. For many reasons, I'm in a position right now where we want to share users between 2 different Firebase projects but don't want to share the whole project with the other.