# How to set/propagate firebase authentication context (UID) for firestore rule configuration for a user coming from another firebase project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a firebase setup for authentication and I would like to make use of firestore security rules to match on the user id so the user can only access his specific data.

Basically I want to be able to set a firestore security rule like this

```
match /users/{uid} {
    allow write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
}
```

However if you want to make use of certain features only available in firestore native mode and you have already setup firestore in datastore mode, you have to setup a new firebase project instead as Google does not allow switching from datastore to native mode.

So how can I setup a firestore security rule that can match on the user id (or other authorization context) for a user that is coming from a firebase project that is not the same as the firestore database?

I have tried a web client with both firebase projects, the auth project and the firestore project and I can access the firestore data as long as I allow anybody to do so but if I try something as simple as saying the user needs to be logged in then it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can I setup a firestore security rule that can match on the user id (or other authorization context) for a user that is coming from a firebase project that is not the same as the firestore database?

That's not possible.  Security rules can only work with users of the same project as the rules.

You could instead create your own backend, and force all user access through that backend.  The code could use the Firebase Admin SDK to [verify a Firebase Auth ID token provided by the client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), then decide in that backend code if that user should be able to access the requested data.

See also:

- [Firebase security rules cross project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62367603/firebase-security-rules-cross-project)

Comment: Thank you. Going through the backend is fine except you're basically missing out on the firestore frontend features such as subscribing to changes in a collection/document. You'd have to reimplement that entire feature yourself instead.

Comment: Guessing switching from datastore mode to firestore mode is not possible even if you don't care about the datastore database and can throw the whole thing away?

Comment: It's not possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434455/how-to-switch-from-datastore-to-firestore-in-existing-project